# Downloading Google Maps data like OSM?

Tags: google-maps, google-earth, google-maps-api

I am working on a project in which I require road network.

I have downloaded data through OpenStreetMap but it is not updated.

Is it possible to download Google Maps data with attributes?

Comment: What software are you using? What tools are you using to download OSM data?

Comment: I am using QGIS to download OSM data, the detailed guidance is available at [link](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to revise it with any requested information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know Google doesn't let you download their data.
It is also important to know that OSM is open source maps and google are kind of the country. 
You can update the OSM file on the Qgis in your PC be clicking the "refresh" bottom. Hopefully the update have new roads data. [image]

Comment: What do you mean by "google are kind of the country"?

Comment: OSM are build as an open source and they encouraged you to use there data as long as you will give them credit. If you want to use google maps and data you need to pay. If not they can sue you